# Catchable fatal error: Object of class dayDaytimeFields could not be converted to string

Tags: php, object

I am trying to render a part of a table using a self created object. 
When trying to access the method in the class I get:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class dayDaytimeFields could not be
>   converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/[...]/test.php on line 85

Line 85 is:

```
$testObj->renderFields();
```

This is my code:

```php
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <caption>Week Planner</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Breakfast</th>
      <th>Lunch</th>
      <th>Dinner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <?php
        class dayDaytimeFields {

            public $dayDaytime;

            public $week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
            public $weekShort = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

            public $dayTime = ['Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner'];
            public $dayTimeShort = ['BrF', 'Lun', 'Din'];

            public function renderFields() {

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->$week); $i++) {

                    echo "<tr><th>" . $this->$week[$i] . "</th>";

                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($this->$dayTime); $j++) {
                        $this->dayDaytime = $this->$weekShort[$i] . $this->$dayTimeShort[$j];
                        echo "<td><input type='text' name='" . $this->dayDaytime . "' id='" . $this->dayDaytime . "'></td>";
                    }

                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>

    <?= 
      $testObj = new dayDaytimeFields();
      $testObj->renderFields(); 
    ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my first step into OOP, so any further input (i.e. how to improve the code) is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: `<?= ` is the shorthand echo syntax and as the error message tells you you are trying to `echo`  a `dayDaytimeFields` which "could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/[...]/test.php on line 85"

Comment: other than @PeeHaa mentioned you have more errors. you are missing `$this->` in lot of places

Comment: PeeHaa and Darragh Enright you were able to help with the most obvious problem. Thank you! @bansi, could you please spot the other errors? I already fixed the forgotten $this-> statements. But there is still no table :-)

Comment: `$this->$week` should be `$this->week` note `$this->$week` has another meaning (variable variable) and so on. no `$` after `->` (you have 5 extra `$` if you didn't find all)

Comment: Well spotted @bansi!

Comment: @bansi wow, you made my day! Thank you very much! I should have known that as I just read it the other day...

Comment: happy learning. whenever you get into trouble we are here to help. nice to hear your problems are fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
<?= 
  $testObj = new dayDaytimeFields();
  $testObj->renderFields(); 
?>
```

First of all, the `<?=` tag is shorthand for:

```
<?php echo
```

So you are essentially doing this:

```
<?php echo $testObj = new dayDaytimeFields(); ?>
```

Which is triggering your catchable fatal error; your class `dayDaytimeFields` obviously does not have a `__toString()` method so you cannot automatically `echo` it.

Actually, it would be more accurate to say that your code is being interpreted like this:

```
<?php echo $testObj = new dayDaytimeFields(); $testObject->renderFields(); ?>
```

If you implemented a `__toString()` method, it would be called and its return value would be printed.

However, the second statement `$testObject->renderFields()` would be called but its value would not be echoed.

Do this instead, assuming that you want to `echo` the return value from `$testObj->renderFields()`:

```
<?php

$testObj = new dayDaytimeFields();
echo $testObj->renderFields(); 

// etc.
```

Hope this helps :)